# Share a common integer?

Tags: c++, ios, visual-c++

I have a common integer needs to be shared by several files.

I created a common.h

I am not sure whether I should use the following

```
static const int level = 2;
```

or just

```
const int level = 2;
```

or just

```
int level = 2;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends, do you want to change the value of the integer or not?

Comment: What is `severe` actually? I'm afraid you're missing to give us a bit more context. Doesn't look like an [tag:ios] related problem for me.

Comment: revise the question. Please ignore severe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At namespace level the `const` implies `static` as default, so it’s unnecessary to specify that explicitly.

Hence, just

```
int const level = severe;
```

Do not omit the `const`, since that permits any code to change the value.

---

However, keep in mind the old adage

> “One man's constant is another man’s configuration value.”

It all depends, but at least in some cases you’re better off with a function to retrieve the value than giving direct access to the value itself.

Then the value might be established from external data.